# How to correctly use the scroll eventListener in vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript

**How can I improve the code below?**

I wish to use only one function to execute my code with the scroll event. I have something like this:

```js
function scrollMenu() {
 window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
   // do stuff
 });
}
function scrollhabilities() {
 let cont = 0;
 window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
   // do stuff
   };
 });
}
```

This works, but I tried to improve the code to be less repetative, however it doesn't work:

```js
const scrollmenu = () =>{}
const scrollhabilities = () =>{}

function scrollThings() {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    scrollmenu();
    scrollhabilities():   
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm sure one error that you will have is you are calling `scrollofmenu` but don't have a function named that.

Comment: I don't recommend adding addEventListeners inside functions.

Comment: @MannyAlvarado why ? i wish learn about it. i tried to put in functions because i wanna make my code more readable. i'm noob in programing.

Comment: @imvain2 i'm sorry its a mistake the function ** scrollofmenu ** its the same as ** scrollmenu ** that you see in the function scrollThings

Comment: You can edit your code to reflect this, and should. It will help you get better suggestions. Also, if you can create a reproduction it will help you get more help.

Comment: *"I don't recommend adding addEventListeners inside functions"* - @MannyAlvarado - are you serious? your statement makes no sense.

Comment: your code works fine.

Comment: @vsync addEventListeners are just that. They listen to events. So they must be readily available when the document loads. They shouldn't expect an execution from a function. Adding addEventListeners inside functions is prone to issues. Just because his code works doesn't mean it's correct.

Comment: @MarcoAntonioTKAS Did either of the below submissions answer your question? If so, please choose a correct answer *to reward the answerer and* ***close out this question***. Doing this would help us out. Remember, also, that you can upvote any answer that was helpful, including the answer that you choose as the correct answer. StackOverflow works by rewarding people who help you, and neither upvoting nor choosing an answer cost you any points - in fact, you earn points for choosing correct answers. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps you to get a starting point. (you can obviously remove the event parameter if you never need it inside the function)

```js
var scrollmenu = function(scrollEvent) {
  console.log('scrollmenu', window.scrollY)
};

var scrollhabilities = function(scrollEvent){
  console.log('scrollhabilities', window.scrollY)
};

var scrollThings = function () {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", event => {
    scrollmenu(event);
    scrollhabilities(event);
  });
}();
```

```css
div.scroll {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">move your cursor here and scroll up and down</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need a debounce function. Debouncing allows your function to fire only once in the specified period of time (500ms in the below example).

Without this function, scrolling the window will fire thousands of times during a continuous scroll. With this function, it will fire only once. As soon as the user pauses for the specified period of time (eg. 500ms), the function will fire. *(I set the timeout to 500ms to ensure the effect is seen - usually you would not specify such a large number - perhaps 100ms or less might be better.)*

Note that there is a companion function called "throttle" that is slightly different.

```js
var cnt = 0;
const msg = document.getElementById('msg');

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    handleScroll();
});

const handleScroll = debounce(() => {
  cnt++;
  msg.innerText = cnt;
},500);

function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

```css
body{height:3000px;}
#msg{
  position:fixed;
  top:20px;
  right:2px;
  padding:2vh 5vw;
  font-size:5rem;
  background:wheat;
  border:1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="msg"></div>
```

#### References:

https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

[this comment explains throttle](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function#comment-80581)

https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/